# Thread locking failing in dead-simple example

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread-safety

This is the simplest toy example.  I know about concurrent.futures and higher level code; I'm picking the toy example because I'm teaching it (as part of same material with the high-level stuff).

It steps on counter from different threads, and I get... well, here it is even weirder.  Usually I get a counter less than I should (e.g. 5M), generally much less like 20k.  But as I decrease the number of loops, at some number like 1000 it is consistently right.  Then at some intermediate number, I get *almost right*, occasionally correct, but once in a while **slightly larger** than the product of nthread x nloop.  I *am* running it repeatedly in a Jupyter cell, but the first line really should reset counter to zero, not keep any old total.

```py
lock = threading.Lock()
counter, nthread, nloop = 0, 100, 50_000 

def increment(n, lock):
    global counter
    for _ in range(n):
        lock.acquire()
        counter += 1
        lock.release()

for _ in range(nthread):
    t = Thread(target=increment, args=(nloop, lock))
    t.start()
    
print(f"{nloop:,} loops X {nthread:,} threads -> counter is {counter:,}")
```

If I add `.join()` the behavior changes, but is still not correct.  For example, in the version that doesn't try to lock:

```py
counter, nthread, nloop = 0, 100, 50_000 

def increment(n):
    global counter
    for _ in range(n):
        counter += 1

for _ in range(nthread):
    t = Thread(target=increment, args=(nloop,))
    t.start()
    t.join()
    
print(f"{nloop:,} loops X {nthread:,} threads -> counter is {counter:,}")
# --> 50,000 loops X 100 threads -> counter is 5,022,510
```

The exact overcount varies, but I see something like that repeatedly.

I don't really want to `.join()` in the lock example, because I want to illustrate the idea of a background job.  But I can wait for the aliveness of the thread (thank you Frank Yellin!), and that fixes the lock case.  The overcount still troubles me though.

Answer (score 2):

You're not waiting until all your threads are done before looking at `counter`.  That's also why you're getting your result so quickly.

```
    threads = []
    for _ in range(nthread):
        t = threading.Thread(target=increment, args=(nloop, lock))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    print(f"{nloop:,} loops X {nthread:,} threads -> counter is {counter:,}")
```

prints out the expected result.

```
50,000 loops X 100 threads -> counter is 5,000,000
```

---

Updated.  I highly recommend using ThreadPoolExecutor() instead, which takes care of tracking the threads for you.

```
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for _ in range(nthread):
            executor.submit(increment, nloop, lock)
    print(...)
```

will give you the answer you want, and takes care of waiting for the threads.

Comment: Sorry.  Can you edit your original posting.  That came out mostly unreadable.  Is the t.join() inside the loop or outside of it?  You need to wait for *all* of your threads.

Comment: Ugh... how do I get formatted block in a comment?

Oh... I know about  ThreadPoolExecutor and concurrent.futures. I'm teaching the material, so want to present the dumb-simple material.  It's not what I would write in my real code.

Comment: Probably can't.  That's why I recommended updating your original posting.  But is your `t.join()` outside the loop?  You're only waiting on the last thread you created, not all of them.  There is no guarantee they finish in the order they were created.

Comment: Thanks Frank... you have been very helpful, and I modified question with formatted code and more details.

Comment: Your version with `t.join()` inside the loop is now essentially a single-threaded program.  You start a thread, and then wait for it to finish before starting the new one.  So your result makes even less sense, since you don't need a lock.  Did you restart python?  It's possible some threads are still running from the previous tests, since you didn't wait for them to finish.  I'm not sure what else to tell you.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I think the mystery overcount must indeed have been in threads that were sticking around from my running lots of soft variations on code.